# Why can't I chain state.get('something').filter with immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

### What am I doing wrong?

I want to filter the *steps* key inside my *state* using `get('..')` and `filter` but I can't manage to do it.

**I have this function:**

```
function visibleSteps(state) {
  return state.get('steps').filter((step) => {
    return step.display
  })
}
```

**When tested with this example:**

```
describe('visibleSteps', () => {
  it('should show the steps with display true and their title', () => {
     const state = Map({
        steps: {
            0: {
                display: false
            },
            1: {
                display: true,
                title: "A title"
            },
            2: {
                display: true,
            },
            3: {
               display: false,
            }
        }
    })

    expect(visibleSteps(state).size).to.equal(2)
  })
})
```

**I get this error:**

```
TypeError: state.get(...).filter is not a function
```

How would the man do this?

Comment: `.filter` is a method of arrays (or other immutable-js types I guess), but not objects.

Comment: Maps can be filtered in immutable.js : https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/filter, my problem is with chaining is after get('steps').

Comment: But the value of `steps` is an object, not a `Map`. If you want a `Map`, you could write `Map({steps: Map({...})})`.

Comment: Thank you Felix, that's right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the value of `steps` is a plain object. Objects don't have a `.filter` method. If you want the value to be a `Map`, you can explicitly create it:

```
const state = Map({
  steps: Map({
    // ...
  })
});
```

Similarly for the most inner objects. If you want a nested JS object/array to be deeply converted to an Immutable `Map`s and `List`s, you can use [**`immutable.fromJS`**](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS).